# Detect mouse click in mfc/ole

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, ole

I am trying to implement a mouse click using mfc in an existant software. The client is a mfc application that is connected to a server through OLE automation. The client display the output of a server that is connect to through OLE. I used the wizared to implement the detection of the mouse click by the client:

```
    void CChildView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
    {
        CDC* pDC1 = GetDC();
        pDC1->SelectStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        pDC1->Ellipse(0,0,20,20);
    }
```

I was expecting that when I click, a small circle will appear. But it doesn't work, I can see only the output of the server! When I implement this in a simple independent project, it works. 
I would appreciate your help to solve this. 
Thanks!
L.

Comment: PLease clarify what you mean by "The client display the output of a server"

Comment: There is a server that records and displays a video. The client has the ability to get this video through the OLE automation and to  display it. This is already done, now at the client side I want to be able to mouse click on the video and that the client be able to detected. For some reason the code above doesn't work with my application, but works in a project without OLE automation. Thanks. L.

Answer (score 1):

If the video is being painted directly on CChildView then it will overwrite and erase the circle very quickly. If the video is being painted by a child control of some kind on the CChildView then the mouse click message goes to that control, not to CChildView.

Comment: Yes the video is painted directly on the CChildView (CChildView::OnPaint() ). I don't think that the painting erase the circle: the click is not detected, the function CChildView::OnLButtonDown is never called, I checked with break points in the debug mode. Thanks. L.

Comment: Check to make sure the message map contains ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()